# ArcGIS buffer wizard tool giving No map units defined

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer

When I click on buffer wizard tool in ArcGIS software, I get an error:

> No map units defined!

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you defined units on the general tab of the data frame properties dialog?

Comment: if you can switch to the gp Buffer tool. A lot more dev and testing efforts have gone into it (and continues to go into it)... additionally it can do a lot more than the buffer wizard.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the Map Units by right clicking on Layers in the table of contents. Here you go to general and you will see Units. You can change it there.

This youtube video shows it too from second 35 onwards:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFaS03m_wh4